# pass Table data cell into Sql string

Tags: c#, sql

so here is my mission. I have a datatable with one single row.  i'm trying to call one cell of data out from the table and pass it into a sql string dynamically for a filter. I do have data in my table when i see it in debug mode. but when i try to view my sql string in a console write line the values are blank, so i'm not sure if test this correctly or writing it incorrectly. I really don't want to deal with a reader since i have to open and close connection multiple times.

```
String sqlpquery = "select * form FeedPreping where path =" + dt.Rows[0]["path"] + " and subdirectory =" + dt.Rows[0]["subd"];
```

After researching i was not able to find any luck with out a loop process. This data table will always have only one row in it. So there is no need for a loop. 
Thanks Tdubs

Answer (score 1):

Besides the usual SQL Injection issues you will face (you should read more about [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)), you're not escaping your strings (assuming path and subdirectory are strings.

You also have a typo in your statement - `form` instead of `from`

Try (notice single quotes around your string data)

```
String sqlpquery = "select * FROM FeedPreping where path ='" + dt.Rows[0]["path"] + "' and subdirectory = '" + dt.Rows[0]["subd"] + "'";
```

As Blake mentions, in the comments you should really be using parameters in your command.

For example

```
string sqlpquery = "select * from FeedPreping where path = @path and subdirectory = @subdir"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlpquery, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", dt.Rows[0]["path"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subdir", dt.Rows[0]["subd"]);
```

Comment: you should add the parameterized version as well as a final answer.
`string sqlpquery = "select * from FeedPreping where path = @path and subdirectory = @subdir; SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlpquery, conn); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", dt.Rows[0]["path"]); ...`

Comment: Actually, SQL is just going to return on syntax error based on `select *` **form**

Comment: @MadMyche - just noticed that myself and added it in

Comment: @BlakeThingstad - didn't feel necessary to. Provided a link to a tutorial that will give far more information than I would like to provide in the answer.

Comment: I personally would still add it because someone who doesn't notice needing ticks around their strings might be overwhelmed with too much information and might be satisfied with the easy answer provided. Up to your discretion though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and also for the typo. lol. I didn't realize that sql injections were vulnerable.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad - fair comment, added it in.

Comment: Ugh, just finished doing the exact same thing but I added `var`s to gold the cell values

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little easier way to read something similar to what you should have.

The syntax error has been corrected ( *form* should be **from** ) and was re-written to use parameters SQL.

I added 2 **vars** to hold your `dt` values so you can do null checking and set defaults if needed or required.

I went with SqlConnection as you do not have a particular flavor of SQL specified.

```
 string sqlpquery = "SELECT * FROM FeedPreping WHERE path = @path AND subdirectory = @subd";

// Added these so you can do a NULL check and default if necessary
var qryPath = dt.Rows[0]["path"];
var qrySubd = dt.Rows[0]["subd"];

 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlpquery, conn)) {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", qryPath);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subd", qrySubd);

           try {
                // sql execution and read here
           }
           catch {
                // exception handling
           }
      }
           conn.Close();
  }
```

Comment: You can put cmd in a using expression as well, it has a Dispose method

Comment: @Blake, I have edited to add. Of note is that MSDN only nests `usings` of this type some of the time. I normally don't, but I usually have full try/catch/finally and disposal.

Comment: I personally just like to use 'using' whenever I can.

Comment: Understandable. I need to run the full `try...finally` routine already. I will try in the future to answer to reflect that most people don't